# How can I process a database with unreliable passwords

Tags: java, sha

I found a website [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) that makes it possible to check if the password is compromised. A database with passwords is also provided. The database looks like a text file

```
000000005AD76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4:10
00000000A8DAE4228F821FB418F59826079BF368:4
00000000DD7F2A1C68A35673713783CA390C9E93:873
```

There are several hundred million values encoded in SHA1, before that the values were converted to uppercase.

I found this:

```java
  public static String generateSHA1(String message) throws RuntimeException {
        return hashString(message, "SHA-1");
    }

    private static String hashString(String message, String algorithm)
            throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            byte[] hashedBytes = digest.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            return convertByteArrayToHexString(hashedBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Could not generate hash from String", ex);
        }
    }

    private static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] arrayBytes) {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte arrayByte : arrayBytes) {
            stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((arrayByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                    .substring(1));
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Should I bring my password (which should be compared with the hashes table) after converting to hash, to a HEX string ?

Is this enough to be able to perform a comparison?

However, I don't understand how to check such a volume :

- After the ':' character, what is this number indicated ?
- To verify, do I have to translate the password value to uppercase and encode using Message Digest with the SHA1 type ?
- However, if I get a hash, then I will have to perform a hash comparison search across the entire database.
- And is it possible to somehow allocate the prefix of the hash string and make a selection of suitable values and search among their range using Java, which will reduce the load on the database and reduce the response of the application?

If anyone has any ideas how to do this and what is this hash in the file, please share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [blog post that explains all this](https://www.troyhunt.com/ive-just-launched-pwned-passwords-version-2/), the `:5` is telling you that this password showed up with separate account information 5 separate times. That one with 873 suggests it's a somewhat commonly used password and in that sense 'worse'.

I don't think the passwords are case insensitive. The API that HIBP provides has case insensitive hash searches, i.e. if you search for `000000005ad76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4`, it finds a hit just as well as `000000005AD76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4`. "Case insensitive" and 'hash it' are not compatible. For a very quick test, check if SHA1(iloveyou) and SHA1(ILOVEYOU) are in the database. if both are, you have your confirmation: Don't mess with cases. If only one is, uppercase (or lowercase) before searching.

Verifying a password's suitability is done as follows:

Take the user's password. Don't mess with its case. SHA1 it. Check if that SHA1 is in this file (the part *before* the colon). If yes, tell the user to go pick something else and [link em to the usual](https://xkcd.com/936/). Especially if the number following the colon is high, that's worse, but appearing *at all* in this list is grounds to deny that password. That `:1234` stuff is mostly for other kinds of research.

> However, if I get a cache, then I will have to perform a hash comparison search across the entire database.

Yes; how else did you think this was going to work? Instead of the 6GB or whatever it is file, you can use their API, even cross-site (each IP is rate limited to one request per 1.5 seconds). Yes, your change pass/create new account form can *directly* ping HIBP with absolutely no involvement from your server, if you want. The HIBP site's API docs explain all this and how to do that. Then *they*<sup>1</sup> will do a search.

For what its worth, searching all that isn't too difficult assuming you do it correctly, that is, indexed. For example, a binary search (I'm pretty sure that file is 'sorted' on SHA1, so look up hashes the way you look up a phone number in a phone book based on somebody's name: Don't just open the book and start reading from Mr. Aabarth, go to the exact middle, check if the name you find there is 'below' or 'above' what you are looking for. If 'below', then take the bottom half of the phonebook, tear it off, toss it in the garbage. You now have half a phonebook to search.

Continue to apply that algorithm: Each time you toss half of what is left in the garbage. That's a LOG2(n) algorithm and therefore will e.g. process in something like 32 steps total ('get rid of half the phonebook' applied 32 times will get you down to a single entry even for a phonebook that has 4 billion entries in it. LOG2(n) is pretty neat).

dbs do this automatically (or can do even better than that) assuming you add an index to the column.

If you actually write this yourself it is smart to build up an index - say, 100k hashes and their exact position in the giant file. To then look up a hash, check your index for that hash that is 'below' your hash but as close to it as possible (you can use `TreeSet` in java for this for example). Open the file, seek to that position, and then start processing until you either [A] find that hash (and deny that password as unsuitable), or [B] you find a hash that is 'higher' (sorts above the hash you have), in which case the password is presumably allright to use. Given that there are something like 4 billion passwords in there, you've now reduced the search to scanning through the file for only 4 billion / 100k = 40,000 hashes, which is going to be near instant, and would be faster than doing a full binary search on the entire file (as hopping around disk sectors is usually pricier even with SSDs), and avoids the difficulty of first seeking to a newline to avoid trying to scan for stuff in the middle of a hash.

[1] *they* is referring to [Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com) who basically runs HIBP as a charity. Consider donating to the cause if you use HIBP!

Comment: we cannot use a third-party API, but can only use an offline database. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: however, when I use Message Digest and get a hash (taking into account UTF-8) as an array of bytes, what format should I convert it to in order to get a string? Maybe it's a 16-bit format? How did the author do it ?

Comment: Might check out the [have-i-been-bloomed](https://github.com/adewes/have-i-been-bloomed) project. I'm sure there are other, similar services that handle this just as well.

Comment: @skyho convert byte array to nibbles. A single byte with `String.format("%02X", byteVal)` - and just concatenate the hash byte arra together with that.

Comment: "....If you actually write this yourself it is smart to build up an index - say, 100k hashes" . Honestly, I was trying to understand your advice. how to speed up everything (it's clear about indexes, I already created an index based on a b-tree on a column with a hash pwd), but could you give an example of your idea. In addition, I still did not understand what kind of

Comment: MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            byte[] hashedBytes = digest.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
and

StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte arrayByte : arrayBytes) {
            stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02X", arrayByte));
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();

 - Is that what you meant? Then I can safely compare the converted password that the client entered with the hashes in the database?

Comment: "Case insensitive" and 'hash it' are not compatible. For a very quick test, check if SHA1(iloveyou) and SHA1(ILOVEYOU) are in the database ... I checked that. Depending on the case, the hash is different.

Comment: @skyho yes, that's how you turn a passsword into a hash. Yes, the hash is different - the question is, are _both_ hashes in the HIBP database? If the answer is 'yes', then you _know_ that HIBP's passwords are stored case sensitive. (And I think that's the case: You said in your question HIBP's password db is case insensitive; I don't think it is, however, and that would be a fine test, given that 'iloveyou' is an incredibly common password).

Comment: @skyho if you have these hashes in a DB right now with an index, you've done hte job - the breakdown on how to quickly look things up in a sorted file using a 100k lookup table is for when you want to, more or less, 'write a db for this purpose from scratch'.

Comment: "the question is, are both hashes in the HIBP database? ... " - This is indeed the case, passwords in this database are case-sensitive. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of methods that helped me convert a plain-text password into a hash, via the **SHA-1** algorithm.  after that, I compared passwords with an offline database of compromised passwords.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String password = "qwerty";

        String pwd = generatePasswordIntoSHA1Algorithm(password);

        System.out.println(pwd);
    }


    public static String generatePasswordIntoSHA1Algorithm(String password) throws RuntimeException {
        return convertPasswordIntoHashString(password, "SHA-1");
    }

    private static String convertPasswordIntoHashString(String message, String algorithm)
            throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);

            byte[] messageInBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            byte[] messageInBytesHashed = digest.digest(messageInBytes);

            return convertByteArrayToHexString(messageInBytesHashed);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Could not generate hash from String", ex);
        }
    }

    private static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] arrayBytes) {

        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte arrayByte : arrayBytes) {

            stringBuffer.append(
                    convertByteToHexFormat(arrayByte)
            );
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    private static String convertByteToHexFormat(byte arrayByte) {
        return String.format("%02X", arrayByte);
    }
}
```